# Best place for user verification using JAAS

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jax-rs, jaas

I am trying to implement the login mechanism using JAAS.
The brief (pseudo) structure of the API looks like this:

1. There is the login resource/controller layer that receives a JSON object from the POST request.

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class LoginController {

    @POST
    public Response getUserDTO(UserForm userForm) {
        // call the LoginService that returns a DTO object.
    }
}
```

2. The deserialized JSON object then is passed to the corresponding service to invoke the login module of JAAS:

```
public class LoginService {
    
    public UserDTO getUserDTO(UserForm userForm) {
        
        // get a user from the database if the user doesn't exist, form a corresponding UserDTO object.
        
        try {
            LoginContext loginContext = new LoginContext("Login", new JAASCallbackHandler(userform);
            loginContext.login();
            // return a corresponding DTO object.
        } catch (LoginException e) {
            // yield a corresponding DTO object based on the validation output
    } 
}
```

3. Then there is the `JAASLoginModule` that implements the `LoginModule` with the following methods:

```
public class JAASLoginModule implements LoginModule {

    @Override
    public boolean initialize(important parameters) {
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean login() throws LoginException {
        return isValidUser(password, username);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean commit() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean abort() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean logout() {
    }

    public boolean isValidUser(password, username) throws LoginException {
        // LoginHelper has been created at this point to move all the verifying logic from the JAASLoginModule
    }
    
}
```

Considering all of them return booleans, it became confusing. To overcome the restrictions related to JAAS `LoginModule`'s return type, the custom exception that extends `LoginException` came to life to make it possible to return a proper `UserDTO` object based on the validation result.
Validation of the user requires a database connection. In this case, it would mean the inevitable query inside the `LoginModule` that is undesirable and hardly manageable based on the boolean fiesta.
To avoid it, the `LoginHelper` arrived.
There is a tiny issue, though. `LoginHelper` doesn't have the user entity from the `LoginModule`, and that means getting the user twice to compare the information:

```
public class LoginHelper {

    public isValidUser(password, username) throws LoginException {
        // get the user from the database... again;
        // verify the user, return true or
        // throw new Custom Exception(user related information for the LoginService);
    }
}
```

Querying the database twice is already an issue. There is no place to move around in `LoginModule` itself, and without the helper and two user entities, it is hard to return the desired DTO object based on the validation result. `LoginService` is responsible for connecting to DAO service and updating the user record in the database based on the received output from the `LoginModule` hence, having the user from the database here is the necessity.

Below you will find a tiny visualization of what is above:

[image: visualization]

I am looking for ideas that will help me to optimize the design a little bit. Even though Hibernate has the cache mechanism inside, the above implementation doesn't feel right.